# Which unitary groups are solvable?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, solvable-groups

I know that if $\zeta$ is a $n^{th}$ primitive root of the unity, we have :$$Gal(\mathbb{Q}[\zeta ]|\mathbb{Q})\cong U(n)$$

Where $U(n)$ is the group of units.

I was wondering, if there were some results on the solvability of these groups.
I know that if $n=pq$ or $n=pqr$ or $n=p^2q$ where $p,q,r$ are distincts primes, then $U(n)$ is solvable.

Is there a generalisation of these results ?

Comment: These are usually not called unitary groups (as that means something else). These are the groups of units of certain rings, and are abelian.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you for the clarification, I will edit my question

Comment: Also, my comment was not just meant to correct the terminology but also to note that the answer is trivially "yes".

Comment: Just to check if I understood I understood : since it is abelian it is solvable. I can use the classifications of abelian groups to prove that. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not use the classification to show that. It completely misses what it means to be solvable.

Comment: Since it is abelian it's commutator subgroup is trivial, so it is solvable ?

Comment: @Jennifer I think the confusion between you and Tobias is that for most people, the definition of solvable is that it admits a filtration by subgroups, each of which is normal in the preceding one, such that quotients are abelian. But you could also define it to be "such that quotients are cyclic."  In the first of these definitions, the result you want is trivial; in the second, it takes some work. Proving these are equivalent is easy; you could use the classification of abelian groups as you say, for example, but you could also show it directly without appeal to that theorem.

Comment: @hunter Ahh, that is a good point.

Comment: @hunter I know these two defintions of solvable groups, but I did not realise that the one involving Commutator subgroup was the good one for this question.

Comment: correct  the galois group of clotomique is not isomorphic the units group $U_n$